# update g++ through synaptic package manager

Tags: 10.04, synaptic, g++

Currently g++ 4.4.3 is installed on my Ubuntu, but I want to update it to 4.6.3 version.
When I search "g++" in synaptic package manager there is nothing about newer versions.

How can I update my g++ then?

Comment: The repository may not contain the newest version. Either try backports or install from source.

Comment: I have ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed the 4.6.3 version. Click on the 'Reload' button on the top left of synaptic and try again.

Comment: @harisibrahimkv: How to install from source?

Comment: @hakermania: Reload didn't change version.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : http://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html

Comment: @harisibrahimkv: Can I do that using `sudo`?

Comment: There are three steps basically. Run the configure script. run make and then make install. You will need 'sudo' for the last one if you are planning to install it in the standard path.

Comment: @harisibrahimkv: Should I unistall anything from my current version?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to install the g++ to a non-standard location (Do this by running ./configure --prefix=<path_to_install_to>) and then append that path to the standard PATH variable. Refer to this http://sosaysharis.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/installing-a-software-from-source-in-ubuntu-untarring-a-tar-tar-gz-file/ . After you are done installing, you can remove your older g++ using "sudo apt-get remove g++".

Answer (score 1):

For latest version of gcc/g++ you can add this ppa-`ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` via Synaptic Package Manager and then press reload button.You should now see the latest version of g++ in the list of packages.